# In R, How can I filter only those rows in which the value for colmun V6 appears exactly 2 times?

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I filter in R only those row in which the value for Column V6 appears exactly 2 times?

my dataseta date:

[image: A screen shot of my dataset]

I try:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- as.data.frame(date)

df1 <- subset(df,duplicated(V6))
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a contingency table to get the value counts. Here's some example code.

```r
# Make some dummy data (only 8 and 2 appear exactly twice in this example)
df <- data.frame(V1=1:10,
                 V2=11:10,
                 V6=c(1,2,8,3,4,3,2,3,8,7))

# Get table of counts for column "V6"
tab <- table(df$V6)

# Get values that appear exactly twice
twice <- as.numeric(names(tab)[tab == 2])

# Filter the data frame based on these values
df <- df[df$V6 %in% twice,]
```

Output:

```
  V1 V2 V6
2  2 10  2
3  3 11  8
7  7 11  2
9  9 11  8
```